# how can I adjust the height of my bootstrap carousel slides when user shrinks the webpage?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have a bootstrap carousel on my webpage. It contains two slides.

The first one has a text and a graphic content, and when user shrinks the webpage horizontally my image disappears (which I made on purpose by adding `hidden-xs`).

The second one contains a text and a form, and when user shrinks the webpage, I don't want to hide any of those elements (rather keep one under another).

The problem is that when webpage is shrinked, the first slide of the carousel contains only one element (text), and the 2nd slide contains two elements (text and form one under another one). So my question is - how can I adjust the height of the carousel so that when the first slide is displayed, the height of carousel is adjusted to the content of text, and when the 2nd slide is displayed the height is adjusted to show text and form?

This is my html code for the carousel:

```
<header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators carousel-indicators-orange">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" id="regularCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" id="businessCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for Slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item itemRegular active" id="regular">
            <div class="parallax"> 
            <div class= "container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <div class="description">  
                            <h5>Some longer text....</h5>
                        </div>       
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5  hidden-xs">
                        <div class="parallax-image" >
                            <img class="phone" src="img/template/image.png">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="item itemCompany" id="business">
            <div class="parallax">
            <div class= "container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-7 company">
                        <h2>title</h2>
                        <div class="secondDescription" >
                           <h5>some longer text</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-5 form-box">
                        <div class="form-top">
                            <div class="form-top-left">
                                <h3>Form title</h3>
                                <p>Fill in the form below:</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-top-right">
                                <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-bottom">
                            <form role="form" method="post" class="registration-form" id="subscribeBusiness">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="form-first-name" placeholder="name..." class="form-first-name form-control" id="form-first-name" name="name" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="form-last-name" placeholder="last name..." class="form-last-name form-control" id="form-last-name" name="last_name" required>
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-fill btn-info pull-left">Sign up</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            </div> 
        </div>    
    </div>
</header>
```

I tried to play around with mobile queries, but the solution seems to me like a workaround and not a typical Responsible Web Design approach. As for now I developed a solution that for each size of the window I'm adjusting height of div `.itemCompany`.

For example I'm doing:

```
@media (max-width: 378px) {
    .itemCompany{
        height:1470px;
     }
}

@media (max-width: 435px) {
     .itemCompany{
        height:1350px;
     }
}
```

and so on, many many mobile conditions depending on each page-width.

Is there any better approach to that than playing around with mobile queries?

Comment: You can try using vh like `height: 100vh;`

Comment: Hmm in which place exactly? as a height of the second slide or the first one?

Comment: How exactly are you arriving at the heights for `.itemCompany` based on the media width?

Comment: Hmm so (please don't laugh) I tried lots of different browser sizes (while resizing the browser with google dev console open) and I was writing down each size and adjust the height accordingly....

Comment: vh is the vertical height of the viewport in percentage.  So if you always want 50%, you'd write 50vh you can put height: 50% in front of that for browsers that don't support vh.  Most do at this point: http://caniuse.com/#search=vh